# External CDROM will not mount

Tags: usb, kubuntu, dvd

This subject is often mentioned - but the threads are very old, so I'll try a new one.
This is on kubuntu 22.04 updated as of this posting date.
I have a Pioneer sata CD/DVD RW drive in an external powered usb-3 enclosure.  I've scanned it every way I know how - but cannot get past the mount error. I also tried filesystem "UDF" - that results in UDF not being valid (it was in an old answer).

> **mount results ->**
> sudo mount -t iso9660 -o ro /dev/cdrom /media/cdrom
> mount: /media/cdrom: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sr0, missing >codepage or helper program, or other error.

> **lsusb provides ->**
> Bus 004 Device 002: ID 174c:55aa ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1051E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, AM1053E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1153 SATA 3Gb/s bridge, ASM1153E SATA 6Gb/s bridge

> **Rescan using scsii-tools provides ->**
>
> Scanning for device 12 0 0 0 ... 
> OLD: Host: scsi12 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
> Vendor: PIONEER  Model: BD-RW   BDR-209M Rev: 1.34
> Type:   CD-ROM                           ANSI SCSI revision: -1

> **lshw provides ->**
>
> *-scsi
> physical id: 2
> bus info: usb@4:4
> logical name: scsi12
> capabilities: emulated scsi-host
> configuration: driver=usb-storage
> *-cdrom
> description: DVD-RAM writer
> product: BD-RW   BDR-209M
> vendor: PIONEER
> physical id: 0.0.0
> bus info: scsi@12:0.0.0
> logical name: /dev/cdrom
> logical name: /dev/sr0
> version: 1.34
> capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
> configuration: status=ready
> *-medium
> physical id: 0
> logical name: /dev/cdrom

I also tried to create a few actions under the removable storage section in settings.  That didn't seem to do anything, so I took it out.

No idea what to do at this point.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR; - install K3b.**

So apparently Kubuntu no longer includes the necessary software to work with CD's and DVD's in the baseline.  I wasn't really looking for a GUI tool - I just want to mount the drive and get some data out of archive. Installing K3b includes all the necessary changes to allow you to work with CD's - including telling Dolphin that the drive exists.  K3b installed and it "just worked."